# How to fix this search filters for both upper case & lover case typing in Angular?

Tags: angular6

I found a search with filters Angular example here yesterday. Tried to make some changes on it and after that couldn't overcome these 2 challenges?

1. When you type the name in lower case it doesn't give any result. It must completely match for working. While how can it be changed? So even if the user searches with lower case and types the correct name it finds the result? At the moment it requires uppercase as it provided in data.
2. How can I implement autocomplete feature? So when a user types first characters it displays suggestions for that input?

Here is the code:

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], value: string): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!value) return items;

        return items.filter(singleItem =>
            singleItem['name'].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        );

    }
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserService } from '../user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html'
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  @Output() autoSearch: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() groupFilters: EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      prefix: new FormControl(''),
      position: new FormControl(''),
      gender: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  search(filters: any): void {
    Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => filters[key] === '' ? delete filters[key] : key);
    this.groupFilters.emit(filters);
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Group Filter</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" 
  formControlName="name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="name"
         #searchText
        />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="prefix">
        <option value="">Prefix</option>
        <option value="MR">MR</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="position">
        <option value="">Position</option>
        <option value="admin">admin</option>
        <option value="student">student</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="gender">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="M">male</option>
        <option value="F">female</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"
              (click)="search(form.value)">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form><br/>
```

How can I solve above mentioned 2 challenges?
If you need the complete example then here is the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-s1xapc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Ffilter.pipe.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1st question : I forked your example and Solve the issue that faced you and enhance the pipe filter to be more generic you can check the solution here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-smz1cb-solved?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Fuser-list%2Fuser-list.component.ts

For 2nd question : I suggest you to use this plugin with angular its documentation is very clear and well organized and you will find your case on it it's :

[ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources)

**Updated**: 

You can find the solution for 2nd question in the same stackblitz link

hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for solving the first one. Is there another way for 2nd one without any additional dependency?

Comment: Yes Of Course ! you can make the same technique they use in their library , you make a div under the input field and put all the items name on it and display the items that includes the user input

Comment: Their code is a bit confusing. I need autocomplete only for name input in the above example. They did something different with select.

Comment: I update my answer with a solution for 2nd question check it !

Comment: It's again with select. I am using just simple input not a select for the name. While you commented the input and used select instead.

Comment: Also, suggestions should appear when you type a character on simple bootstrap input as I used.

Comment: I think you will have to make a lot of work and wrap the name input with another component to display the names first and make a bind value with input event of name input and this component and apply the same pipe filter to it and also handle the enter event and click event when user did that I think ng-select make all of that for you already

Comment: Just upvoted your answer.  I really appreciate your help. Decided to remove autocomplete fully.  One more question I've added 2 age inputs for a range. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-smz1cb-solved-jx6kgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Ffilter.pipe.ts

Should I ask a separate question for that? How to configure pipe for that age inputs display the results between those 2 values?

Comment: Of Course ! I think this will be manual checking in the user-list.component.ts which you will check if the ageto & agefrom is filled with data and make a filter function to filter the result after the other filters is applied and the pipe will not be the best solution for that

Comment: I've posted a new question for that including the other pipe as well. If you could help with that it would be great.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444031/how-to-use-this-pipe-with-another-one-in-this-code-for-filtering-the-data-in-ang?noredirect=1#comment93761988_53444031