# How to use this pipe with another one in this code for filtering the data in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

I've added to form inputs that will filter users by age ranges. Created pipe for that. Now I am trying to implement that in the working example where were used other pipe for filtering results based on other forms. How can I use age range pipe in this working example and make those 2 pipes work together? Here is the code:

**Age range pipe**

```
     transform(value: any, args?: any): any
 { if(!args) return value;
 return value.filter( item => item.age > args[0] && item => item.age < args[1])
     );
     }
```

Where args[0] is min value and args[1] max value.

**Pipe of working search example**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], value: string, prop: string): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!value) return items;

        return items.filter(singleItem =>
            singleItem[prop].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        );

    }
}
```

**TypeScript of working example**

```
form: FormGroup;

  @Output() autoSearch: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() groupFilters: EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter<any>();
  searchText: string = '';
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      prefix: new FormControl(''),
      position: new FormControl(''),
      gender: new FormControl(''),
      agefrom: new FormControl(''),
      ageto: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  search(filters: any): void {
    Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => filters[key] === '' ? delete filters[key] : key);
    this.groupFilters.emit(filters);
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate
      [formGroup]="form">

  <h3>Group Filter</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" 
  formControlName="name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="name"
         #searchName
        />
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" 
  formControlName="agefrom"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="age from"
         #searchName
        />
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" 
  formControlName="nageto"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="age to"
         #searchName
        />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="prefix">
        <option value="">Prefix</option>
        <option value="MR">MR</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="position">
        <option value="">Position</option>
        <option value="admin">admin</option>
        <option value="student">student</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="gender">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="M">male</option>
        <option value="F">female</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"
              (click)="search(form.value)">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form><br/>
```

**For the full code example you can check here:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-smz1cb-solved-jx6kgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Ffilter.pipe.ts

How can I implement that age range pipe in the code and make it the part of this working example?

Comment: You can achieve this by using two separate filters, else you need to work on generic filter. let me know what you want to achieve. like complexity vs simplicity.

Comment: I need just any simple way to make this age range inputs filters work as good as other ones do. The only challenge is implementing that age range inputs filter in the mentioned working example and make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve your problem but without using pipes I make the logic in the filter function you made in the (user-list.component.ts) you can check it here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-smz1cb-solved-age-range?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Fuser-list%2Fuser-list.component.html

Hope my answer help you

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. Just one question. When I remove <th> and <td> for name or age inputs search still works which is great but when I remove <th> and <td>  for those data that were used with select filters it doesn't filter anymore? What's the difference for those ones? I am asking it because in the real app not all dates from backend should be displayed on the screen but search should work. It's very interesting case that happens only for select.

Comment: I think is because when filter function executes it give you an error when make the check of the user['age'] because of the empty field but I add a safe type checking now in the code and make a sample with the case when age is not sent and the filters works again!

Comment: Nope. I mean age and name were worked perfectly when the <Td> and <th> were not there. That trouble is with gender, prefix and another one which are selects instead of inputs.

Comment: I know the problem because of in keys filters I don't make a safe checking for them and also if they aren't in obj so we append false to the result array I updated the stackblitz with the new solution with an example which meets your case

Comment: It seems I can't explain enough well. It's not the case :D You just added conditions in HTML part.  Here is what exactly I want to explain:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values-smz1cb-solved-age-range-ulqfog?file=src/app/user/user-list/user-list.component.html
I removed name and prefix fully. But when you search by name it works which is correct. When you select from prefix it doesn't work.  For the name, it gets data from backend correctly. But for a prefix which is select, it doesn't.

Comment: I added a logic inside the function of the filter you didn't see it I think , It works fine with the stackblitz you provide now with prefix , position & gender even if they aren't here because It doesn't matter to angular if they appear in the html or not , you just decide which values you want to display

Comment: Thanks once again for your help :) Now It works fine!

Comment: Shorbagy if we add   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination  on it will it still filter through the whole user list or will filter only first page?

Comment: the auto search will be only for the visible part of the current page of pagination, but the search component you will apply the filters to the whole array of users so it will catch them all

Comment: @Shorbagy  I found your answer during the research but have faced to the issue when tried to include it in my project. All input filters are working but select filters doesn't. Can you please help me? I posted question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362473/select-filters-are-not-working-in-angular